# Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined

Tags: php, xml, dom

I am running a request to an xml file like this :

```
function load()
{
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "response.xml", true);
    request.send();

    request.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (request.readyState == 4)
        {
            var x = request.responseXML;
            var y = x.getElementsByTagName("Limits")[0].childNodes[1];
            var z = y.getElementsByTagName("Limits")[0].childNodes[0];
            document.write(z);
        }
    };
}
```

The xml `response.xml` is this:

```
<Factory>
    <Limits>
        <Point X="92" Y="489">hahahahff</Point>
        <Point X="570" Y="487">1111</Point>
        <Point X="570" Y="138">33333</Point>
        <Point X="92" Y="140">44444444</Point>
        <Point X="92" Y="139">5555555</Point>
    </Limits>
    <Cells>
        <Cell>
            <Point X="358" Y="138"/>
            <Point X="361" Y="487"/>
            <Point X="570" Y="487"/>
            <Point X="570" Y="138"/>
            <Point X="358" Y="138"/>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
            <Point X="311" Y="139"/>
            <Point X="311" Y="488"/>
            <Point X="92" Y="489"/>
            <Point X="92" Y="140"/>
            <Point X="311" Y="139"/>
        </Cell>
    </Cells>
</Factory>
```

I get this error:

> **Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined**

why is this happening ?

What I am trying to achieve is print the value of the 2nd `POINT` node WITHOUT using `getElementsByTagName("POINT")[1]`.

Basically I want to 'enter' the Limits node, and print the 2nd value.

Comment: The error means that `getElementsByTagName` is returning an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
var z=y.getElementsByTagName("Limits")[0].childNodes[0];
```

should be:

```
var z=x.getElementsByTagName("Limits")[0].childNodes[0];
```

`x` is what got from the previous line, so it's already a child of `Limits`. So this line was trying to find `Limits` inside the child of `Limits`, and there is no nested `Limits` like that.