# Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined but list works

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I have the following code that should return two child node values from each parent node in an xml file.

```html
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>

<head>
  <title> ADM Asset Availability </title>
  <!--  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"> -->
</head>

<body onload="AssetUpdate()">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var xhttp;
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        AssetUpdate(this);
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "Assets.xml", true);
    xhttp.send();

    function AssetUpdate(xml) {
      var n, x, i, txt, xmlDoc;
      xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
      txt = "";
      x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Asset");

      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        var txt1 = "<dvi class='rowContainer'>";
        var txt2 = x[i].getElementsByTagName("AssetName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var txt3 = "-";
        var txt4 = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Live")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var txt5 = "</div>";
        txt += txt1 + txt2 + txt3 + txt4 + txt5;
      }
      document.getElementById("Asset").innerHTML = txt;
    };
  </script>

  <div id="Asset">

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

`txt2` returns the requested value with no problem whatsoever. However, `txt4` (which is structured exactly) causes an error detected in the browser of

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined at AssetUpdate  AssetPage.php:33)

I have tried about 30 variations of the code, loop and tag names still resulting in the same error.

Please help

This is the xml for referance;

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><Assets>
<Asset>5
    <AssetID>1</AssetID>
    <AssetName>Laser</AssetName>
    <Live>Test</Live>
</Asset>
<Asset>7
    <AssetID>2</AssetID>
    <AssetName>Press</AssetName>
    <Live>Test1</Live>
</Asset>
<Asset>9
    <AssetID>3</AssetID>
    <AssetName>Fab</AssetName>
    <Live>Test2</Live>
</Asset>
<Asset>blue
    <AssetID>78</AssetID>
    <AssetName>Paint</AssetName>
    <Live>Test3</Live>
</Asset></Assets>
```

I have checked and found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697486/cannot-read-property-childnodes-of-undefined) but not made the mistake identified in that thread.

**EDIT**

```
Navigated to http://localhost/ADMApp/AssetPage.php 
AssetPage.php:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'responseXML' of undefined
at AssetUpdate (AssetPage.php:24)
at onload (AssetPage.php:6)
AssetUpdate @ AssetPage.php:24
onload @ AssetPage.php:6
AssetPage.php:34 HTMLCollection []length: 0__proto__: HTMLCollectionitem: ƒ 
item()arguments: (...)caller: (...)length: 1name: "item"__proto__: ƒ 
()apply: ƒ apply()arguments: (...)bind: ƒ bind()call: ƒ call()caller: 
(...)constructor: ƒ Function()length: 0name: ""toString: ƒ 
toString()Symbol(Symbol.hasInstance): ƒ [Symbol.hasInstance]()get arguments: 
ƒ ()set arguments: ƒ ()get caller: ƒ ()set caller: ƒ ()__proto__: 
Object[[FunctionLocation]]: <unknown>[[Scopes]]: Scopes[0][[Scopes]]: 
Scopes[0]length: (...)namedItem: ƒ namedItem()constructor: ƒ 
HTMLCollection()Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ 
values()Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "HTMLCollection"get length: ƒ 
length()__proto__: Object
AssetPage.php:35 undefined
AssetPage.php:36 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of 
undefined
at AssetUpdate (AssetPage.php:36)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange (AssetPage.php:15)
AssetUpdate @ AssetPage.php:36
xhttp.onreadystatechange @ AssetPage.php:15
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
(anonymous) @ AssetPage.php:19
AssetPage.php:19 XHR finished loading: GET 
"http://localhost/ADMApp/Assets.xml".
(anonymous) @ AssetPage.php:19
```

I don't know a better way to display this error coding so please educate me if this isn't right (also image of the actual display below).

If you need me to fully expand the HTMLCollection then let me know but it is a very big cascade.

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3BUy.png)

Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Start to debug and print the whole txt4 step by step to the console like
consloe.log(x[i]);
consloe.log(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Live"));
consloe.log(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Live")[0]);
Etc. And see what you get.

Comment: @KataCsortos fix `consloe` to `console`

Comment: @barbsan can't edit my  prev comment now but yes, type `console.log` instead of `consloe.log`

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the quick responses. I have added in the log as you have suggested but I can't say I have learnt much from it. I will edit the main post with the log file/pic or something ASAP.

Comment: As may not be clear in the original post I also get a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'responseXML' of undefined" error. The code always seems to generate this error but will still work. Could this however lead to the secondary error when called a second time?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I would still appreciate any other input but as far as I can tell I haven't changed anything but running it on a different computer works. And having restarted my PC after running it on a different computer it works as well....
My thinking is that it was a problem with my local-host server that resolved itself on restart.?

Thanks
Connor